# Add line to the tablix header

Tags: c#, rdlc

I'm using Windows forms in c# and use rdlc reports.

I need to design a report as follows

Id    Name

---

01   AAA

02   BBB

03  CCC

I added tablix to the rdlc and I could create report and display data as I want. But I have a problem when displaying the line after the headers.

This line need to be shown with the width of the report even two columns in the grid. Even I add a line to the after the header of the tablix, it doesn't get repeated in every page. How can I overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set bottom border of each headers?

[image]

You could set it by **select each header cell**, then right click and select `Text Box Properties`>`Border`>`Preview`.